# Why does this compile? cout<"Yes";

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     cout<"Yes"; 
}
```

it compiles, but when it runs, it does nothing. this is a compilation error elsewhere.
compiler is gcc 4.9.2

compared with

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
         cout<<"Yes"; 
    }
```

it has a missing '<' but it still compiles.

I expected it to be a compilation error, as with variables, like this:

```
> 6 6   C:\Users\Denny\Desktop\Codes\compileerror.cpp   [Error] no match for
> 'operator<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka
> std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'int')
```

this happens with the code below as well.

```
   #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
         cin>"Yes"; 
    }
```

edit:
The same thing happens for

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    
    std::cout<"Yes";
}
```

plus, I enabled compiler warnings and there are none.

Comment: Did you mean to write `cout << "Yes";`?

Comment: Please provide your code as text in a correctly formatted [mcve]. You should also explain why you think it *shouldn't* compile.

Comment: Don't post code as images, copy paste your code directly in the question.

Comment: There are a lot of typos that result in syntactically correct code.

Comment: GCC 4.9.2 is pretty outdated, you might try a newer one – though wondering why there's a less operator for `std::ostream` and pointers (if it compiles, as you say)...

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: Why this question was closed ? Until C++11, basic_ios has `operator void*()` so cout is casted to pointer, then < is used to compare two pointers.

Comment: I would consider voting to reopen if you posted your text as text, not as links or images.

Comment: If you enable compile warnings, you should get "expression result unused" or a similar warning.

Comment: In fact, none of the recent versions of some major compilers does accept your broken code: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vPsPfGnGP) (while gcc v4.9.2 accepts both).

Comment: This is now a pretty good question. Nice update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default C++ standard in GCC<6.1 (which includes your 4.9.2) is `gnu++98`, while for GCC≥6.1 it's `gnu++14` (as documented e.g. [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)). Thus the latter compiler won't accept this code by default, due to `explicit operator bool()` being present in the iostreams since C++11 instead of `operator void*()` in C++98 (see e.g. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)).

You could have been warned if you had turned on the warnings:

```
$ g++-4.8 test.cpp -o test -Wall
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:15: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
     std::cout < "Yes";
               ^
```

where `test.cpp` contains example code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout < "Yes";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Prior to C++11, the way that `if (std::cin >> var)` was supported was the stream objects having an implicit conversion to `void *`.

So `std::cout<"Yes"` is evaluated as calling the built in `bool operator<(void*, const void*)`, after applying the conversions `std::basic_ios` -> `void *` and `const char[4]` -> `const char*` -> `const void*`.

Since C++11, there is now a rule that an `explicit` conversion to `bool` can be used in `if`, `while` etc. With that, the `operator void*` was changed to be `explicit operator bool`, and overload resolution correctly finds no match for `std::cout<"Yes"`

Comment: I'd like to add that g++ 4.9.2 accepts this broken code even with `-std=c++11 -pedantic` ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Yaa1q49d8)). It's probably simply too old to handle this correctly.

Comment: `void*, char const*` operator? Isn't that `void*, void*` instead?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat one difference of 4.8 from 5.5 (versions that I have locally) is that the former defines `basic_ios::operator void*()` unconditionally, while the latter defines it only for `__cplusplus < 201103L`. I suppose 4.8 doesn't differ much from 4.9 in this regard.